# Compile time initialized array error

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, pcspim

I am trying to make an array to which I have provided the data at compile time in MIPS. but I am getting error and thus the code is not getting compiled. Here is the chunk of code which is causing error.

```
.data

array: .space 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'
```

What is the reason for error? If you know any tutorials which explain arrays of `.space`, `.byte` and `.word`, please mention them in answer.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `.space` directive for initialized arrays. `.space` is for reserving N uninitialized bytes. You can use `.byte` or `.word` for such purpose, depending on the size of your data. In your example, you're using ASCII characters, so `.byte` should be OK.

```
.data

array: 
.byte 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'
```

Any MIPS assembly reference should be OK. Here's [one](http://gicl.cs.drexel.edu/people/sevy/architecture/MIPSRef%28SPIM%29.html).

Comment: but with .byte I get "Memory Address out of bound error"? What should I do

Comment: add $s4,$t1,$t0

lb $a0,0($s4)       

li $v0,4       

syscall        when the simulator executes this statement, the error is generated

Comment: You didn't post the code. Also I recommend [MARS MIPS simulator](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/), for me way better than SPIM.