# Memory Out of bound error

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, pcspim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compile time initialized array error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881850/compile-time-initialized-array-error)

I am trying to load data from a compiled time initialized array. But when I try to load the data, I get "Memory OUt of bound error". Here is the code:

```
.data

array: .space 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'

.text

 main:
 .
 .
 .

 la $t0,array

# $t1 is intialized to 0 and then incremented in code later for next loading
add $s4,$t1,$t0

 lb $a0,0($s4) # Here is error "Memory out of bound"

 li $v0,4

 syscall
```

How can I solve this issue? I am using QTSpim

Regards

Answer (score 1):

`.space` reserves empty space, without data in it. You should use:

```
.asciiz "ABCDEFGHI"
```

Comment: but I want to store the result again in this array. Basically it is a part of 15 Puzzel game

Comment: That's no problem. You can write to this array.

Comment: But can't I do it with the .byte type array.

Comment: Yes, but the effect is the same. Personally, I like this better, because it is shorter and cleaner, but .byte will also work.